# Swift combine get custom objects from AnyPublisher

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fetch 'Post' objects from the API with AnyPublisher, but I'm unable to get the result. How can we achieve result from `AnyPublisher<[Post], Error>`

Here is my code,

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

struct Post: Decodable{
    var id: Int
    var userId: Int
    var body: String
    var title: String

}

protocol API {
    var baseUrl: String { get }
    var path: URL { get }
}

enum PostService: API {

    var baseUrl : String { "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" }
    case all
    var path: URL {
        switch self {
        case .all:
            return URL(string: baseUrl + "/posts")!
        }
    }

    func fetch(from url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<[Post], Error> {
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: [Post].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
}

PostService.fetch(.all)  
// how to get all posts here
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to that publisher `PostService.fetch(.all).sink(....)`. Just ready any basic tutorial about Combine, it should cover this

Comment: I tried that getting error something like "Value of type '(URL) -> AnyPublisher<[Post], Error>' has no member 'sink''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong, at least the way you are calling it, I assume it should be something like this

```swift
enum PostService: API {

    var baseUrl : String { "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" }
    case all
    var path: URL {
        switch self {
        case .all:
            return URL(string: baseUrl + "/posts")!
        }
    }

    func fetch() -> AnyPublisher<[Post], Error> {
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: path)
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: [Post].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
}
```

then you would be able to subscribe to it like so

```swift
PostService.all.fetch().sink { completion in

} receiveValue: { posts in

}
```

If you really want to keep call syntax the way you wrote it, you would need to update your code like this

```swift
enum PostService: API {

    var baseUrl : String { "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" }
    case all
    var path: URL {
        switch self {
        case .all:
            return URL(string: baseUrl + "/posts")!
        }
    }

    static func fetch(from url: Self) -> AnyPublisher<[Post], Error> {
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url.path)
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: [Post].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
}
```

note the `fetch` method is static now